# Directory not created in the linux server by php code

Tags: php, linux

I have been trying to create a directory in linux server by using the below php script,

```
mkdir("/var/test", 0777);
```

but for some reason its not getting created and it does not give any message about the outcome(error) once the script is run.

What i want to know is how do i get the error out after running the scripts(i tried to check the apache logs but could not find them) and will anybody be able to find the reason why the directory is not creating

**/var is on 0755 permission level

Comment: Add sudo before mkdir and/or change owner accordingly (chown)

Comment: sorry, i do add sudo!! :)

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
$output = shell_exec('mkdir /var/test');
print $output;
```

What is the output? Any errors?

Comment: im not getting any error or response... and the directory is not created either

Answer (score 0):

Probably display of errors is suppressed in the php.ini file.
To override that and display errors at runtime place the following line at the top of your php script `init_set("display_errors","1")`. This will definitely display the error so you know what to do to correct it. `mkdir()` throws 2 kinds of errors with the `E_WARNING` level. 1 is when the directory already exists and the other when you do not have sufficient permission to write to the target path.
Check these documentations
`init_set()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php
`mkdir()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php